# Feature Selection using Rough Set Theory

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, feature-selection

I have a python coding for feature selection using rough set theory. This is a quick reduct algorithm. However, I can't produce the output since it runs very slow for high dimensional dataset. It can takes days to run the coding but still I cannot produce the output. Can anyone give any suggestions to solve this problem ?

```
from itertools import combinations
import itertools
from itertools import chain, combinations
# do not change
reduct=[]
stuff = allAttributesName
# stuff = [1, 2, 3]
for i, combo in enumerate(powerset(stuff), 1):
    if len(combo)>0 and i>0:
        ll=[]
        abc=[]
        for index in range(0,len(combo)) :
            ll.append(combo[index])
#         print(ll)
        indList=[]
        indList=indiscernibility(ll,dtm_df)
        indList = list(filter(None, indList))
        for m in range(0,len(indList)) :
            flag=0
            tl=[]
            for n in range(0,len(indList[m])) :
                for pr in positiveRegionValue :
                    if indList[m][n]==pr :
                        tl.append(indList[m][n])

            if len(tl)>0 :
                abc.append(tl)
        cc=0
        for x in INDC:
            for y in abc :
                if len(y)==len(x) :
                    temp=set(x) & set(y)
                    if len(temp)==len(y) :
                        cc=cc+1
#                         print(temp)
        if(cc==len(INDC)) :
#             print("Matched")
            reduct.append(ll)

`
```

Comment: You'll probably need to give some more information about the size and dimension of your data set. Are you hunting for a bug (e.g. because you know other implementations run much quicker on the same size data), or are you after optimization suggestions, or alternative algorithms, because this one is too slow on this amount of data?

Comment: @DarrenCook my size of dataset is 2000 rows and 100 columns. I'm currently doing research in feature selection in sentiment analysis. The feature selection method used here is rough set theory. Is there any alternative algorithms or optimization that can be used to replace this algorithms. This algorithms is too slow for my dataset. It takes 3 days to run this algorithm but still it didn't manage to produce any output